# Sending push notification to a particular user in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm having a devil of a time trying to do what seems like the simplest possible thing: I want to send a push notification to a particular user, and I already have the PFUser object for that user.

I tried the following:

```
// 'recipient' is the PFUser
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"owner" equalTo:recipient];
```

I also tried replacing "owner" with "user". In both cases, the push seems to succeed (no error reported) but the device never gets the notification.

I know that the device is properly registered and logged in because I can send pushe notifications from the Parse web console.

What's the right way to do this?

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a nested query to get this.

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.equalTo('objectId', recipient);

var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', userQuery);
```

Comment: PFQuery* userQuery = [PFUser query];
 [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:recipient.objectId];
 
 PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
 [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:userQuery];

Comment: Oh, silly me. Yes, that was JavaScript that I used in a Cloud Code function. Have you considered writing this as a Cloud Code function instead?

Comment: Do you have to store a column like `user[Installation] = PFInstallation.current` for the `_User` document? Can you help me check out whether this is set up correctly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089809/parse-cloud-pushquery-matchesquery-never-sends-push-notification-to-receiver

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it turns out that this is a two-step process.

When the user logs in or creates an account, you have to put a "user" property in PFInstallation:

```
    [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
    [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveEventually];
```

Only then will the query work.

That seems like a lot of manual work for something that the Parse server should know without my having to set it up.